# Mvvmcross issues with fluent binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am quite new Mvvmcross implementation for android app development .
While I found binding quite similar yet I am facing a minor issue with binding .
Whenever I am trying to bind a textview or button click event in code below issue is coming .

```
         var set = this.CreateBindingSet<WelcomeView, WelcomeViewModel>();
        set.Bind(titleTxt).To(viewModel => viewModel.Welcome);

        set.Bind(subtitleTxt).To(viewModel => viewModel.ShareTitleText);
        set.Bind(joinBtn).For(zm => zm.Click).To(viewModel => viewModel.ShowDataPrivacyCommand);
```

last lines gives problem saying "Event view.click can only appear left side of += or -= .

so how do I get over it ?
I know binding in xaml works I am looking to do it in code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click is an event handler so you can't bind to that. You can only bind to properties. In case of a `UIButton` you can use the binding extension `BindTouchDown` or bind to the command directly:

```
set.Bind(joinBtn).To(vm => vm.ShowDataPrivacyCommand);
```